# How to open a port in Windows firewall on Google cloud console

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a VM Windows server 2012 running in Google cloud which is not being able to RDP after accidentally updated in Firewall (of the VM).

Is it possible to update the VM's firewall from GCP console ?

Any idea to fix this is much appriciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Google documentation, you can connect to your server via PSESSION.
First, You need to open port 5986 from your [GCP Firewall.](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list)

Then Open Powershell on your local computer and type in this command:

> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName [EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] -UseSSL
>   -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck)
>   -Credential $credentials

If the port is blocked from your windows firewall, then you can try accessing CMD from Serial Console.

 Instructions Available [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance)

[image]

After you have access to your CMD/Powershell, you can easily turn them off with this command:

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

If all of above fails, you can try doing it through startup script:
[Documentation Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances)

Hope This helps,
Shahriar

Comment: On the Console tab, There is info about how you can access SAC from your browser. Additional documentation about SAC is available here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc787940(v=ws.10)

Comment: Thanks for the great help, I'm able to connect via serial port from gcp console.